# MongoDB $gte fails to match nested document's field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to query a simple JSON to return all matches where `values.time` is greater than 10:

```
{ key: "key1",
  values: [
    "{\"object\":\"some object1\",\"time\":11}",
    "{\"object\":\"some object2\",\"time\":9}",
  ]
}
```

The query is done through the Java API:

```
FindIterable<Document> documents = collection.find(gte("values.time", 10));
```

Please review the update and find commands as reported by mongo:

```
10:13:10.126 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Sending command '{"update": "collection1", "ordered": true, "$db": "db1", "updates": [{"q": {"key": "key1"}, "u": {"$push": {"values": "{\"object\":\"some object\",\"time\":11}"}}}]}' with request id 31 to database db1 on connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:35}] to server localhost:27017
10:13:10.128 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Execution of command with request id 31 completed successfully in 2.02 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:35}] to server localhost:27017
10:13:10.130 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Sending command '{"find": "collection1", "filter": {"values.time": {"$gte": 10}}, "$db": "db1"}' with request id 32 to database db1 on connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:35}] to server localhost:27017
```

Yet there is never a match found.  What am I doing wrong?  Answers using the Java API are preferred.

Comment: Your `time: "11"` is a string you're comparing it with number `10` - it doesn't work like that..

Comment: @whoami transcription error.  Fixed the post, thanks

Comment: Check the result of the update command.  If it doesn't find a document matching the query part, it won't perform any updates, but that is still a successful completion.  The result should indicate how many documents were updated.

Comment: @Joe I confirm the update was successful by looking at the database.  Sure enough, the value is there.  I've updated the JSON that is being queried, as it was not exactly accurate.

Comment: Your `value` array contains Strings, not JSON. That's why you get 0 results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document you show:

```
{ key: "key1",
  values: [
    "{\"object\":\"some object1\",\"time\":11}",
    "{\"object\":\"some object2\",\"time\":9}",
  ]
}
```

Contains 2 fields - `key` contains a string, and `values` contains an array of strings.

You can test this by running this aggregation:

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
        {$match: {key: "key1"}},
        {$project: { 
              valueType:{
                     $map:{
                       input:"$values",
                       in:{$type:"$$this"}
                     }
               },
               _id:0
        }}
])
```

The element you are pushing is also a string, not an object.

If you replace both of these strings with actual objects, it should work.